# MySQL 5.7 - JSON Indexing - Generated Columns with non-scalar values

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-5.7

I have been playing with the JSON support in MySQL 5.7 . I have a few questions about the generated columns for the purpose of indexing. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html#create-table-secondary-indexes-virtual-columns .

Specifically, refer to this line:

> JSON columns cannot be indexed. You can work around this restriction by creating an index on a generated column that extracts a ***scalar*** value from the JSON column.

This seems to be a big limitation for me. Everywhere I look, people suggest using generated columns. But that workaround would work for a very limited set of use-cases. Or, I am understanding something wrong.

### Setting the stage

Let me explain my use-case. Suppose you have a table called `standards`. It has the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `standards` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `sections` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `subjects` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

The `sections` column contains an array of JS objects:

```
[
  {
    "id": 90491,
    "name": "A",
  },
  {
    "id": 90494,
    "name": "B",
  }
]
```

The `subjects` column contains a nested JS object:

```
{
  "576845": {
    "id": 576845,
    "name": "Computer Education"
  },
  "576848": {
    "id": 576848,
    "name": "English Language"
  },
  "576854": {
    "id": 576854,
    "name": "Environmental Science"
  },
  "576860": {
    "id": 576860,
    "name": "Mathematics"
  }
}
```

### Example Queries

#### Query 1

To find a `Standard` record which has a `section ID` of `90494`, the query would be:

```
SELECT * from standards WHERE JSON_CONTAINS( sections->>'$[*].id', '90494' );
```

#### Query 2

To find a `Standard` record which has the `subject ID` of `576854`, the query would be:

```
SELECT * from standards WHERE JSON_CONTAINS_PATH( subjects, 'one', '$."576854"');
```

OR

```
SELECT * from standards WHERE JSON_CONTAINS( subjects->>'$.*.id', '576854' );
```

### Problem

Now, all the above works. The problem is that the queries perform a full table scan.

Considering Query 1 from above, how can I generate a virtual column with *scalar* data which contains ALL `section IDs`?

Each `Standard` record has multiple `sections`, with multiple IDs. So, I can't just create an integer virtual column to store a single value. It has to be an array of section IDs, through which we need to search.

So, my generated column would be like below:

```
ALTER TABLE standards
ADD section_ids json GENERATED ALWAYS AS (sections->>'$[*].id') VIRTUAL NOT NULL;
```

The generated column will now store just the array of section IDs. But I cannot add an index on the generated column, because it is again a JSON column.

### Question - How to utilize index?

So, the question comes down to this - for my queries shown above, how do I avoid full table scans?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Currently not feasible in MySQL, see [Indexing JSON documents via Virtual Columns by MySQL Server Blog](http://mysqlserverteam.com/indexing-json-documents-via-virtual-columns/#comment-13274).

Comment: That's a shame. In the blog you have linked to, the author has commented, as recently as 3 days ago, to say that "JSON array indexing" is still "on the roadmap". So, I guess this is not going to be supported any time soon.

Answer (score 2):

I won't say it isn't possible with MySQL 5.7 - because it is, with clunky workarounds and limitations - but I will not go into a how-to with that version as it is much more difficult and the limitations will, in many cases, be reached if a large number of items can be added to the array.

However, it is possible as of MySQL [8.0.17](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-17.html#mysqld-8-0-17-feature) which now supports [multi-valued indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-multi-valued).

```
ALTER TABLE standards
  ADD INDEX section_ids ( (CAST(sections->'$[*].id' AS UNSIGNED ARRAY)) ),
  ADD INDEX subject_ids ( (CAST(subjects->'$.*.id'AS UNSIGNED ARRAY)) );
```

** Note that `$.*` will take all object properties and return the queried values (`.id`) of each formatted as an array.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * from standards WHERE JSON_CONTAINS( sections->'$[*].id', '90494' );
EXPLAIN SELECT * from standards WHERE JSON_CONTAINS( subjects->'$.*.id', 576854 );
```

You will see that the indexes are used for those queries.

Answer (score -1):

I would solve this in older versions by manually creating a separate index table, and using triggers to keep it up to date.